Rule based dictionary manipulation in python
I have the following code that creates a dict with the keys (t,d). I have the lists T for the therapists and D for the days. Currently the same value for d is assigned for each therapist t. But I want it to be rule-based. So for each t in T, a random day d<6 should be "drawn". The value there is then replaced by 0. The same game for day d+1. Then the previous value should remain five times, then 0 twice again and then the value five times again. Until the end of Len(D). The pattern does not have to end at the end. How does that work?
This is the code:
import random

T = list(range(1, 3))
D = list(range(1, 15))

random_values_for_t = {t: random.randint(1, 4) for t in T}

Max_td = {(t, d): random_values_for_t[t] for t in T for d in D}

print(Max_td)

This is the initial list:
{(1, 1): 4, (1, 2): 4, (1, 3): 4, (1, 4): 4, (1, 5): 4, (1, 6): 4, (1, 7): 4, (1, 8): 4, (1, 9): 4, (1, 10): 4, (1, 11): 4, (1, 12): 4, (1, 13): 4, (1, 14): 4}

Now, for example, d=3 is chosen as the initial value. Then every value for d<3 stays the same and the d and d+1 become zero. Then the next 5 values stay the same and again two become zero and so on until the end of len(D). The list should now look like this.
{(1, 1): 4, (1, 2): 4, (1, 3): 0, (1, 4): 0, (1, 5): 4, (1, 6): 4, (1, 7): 4, (1, 8): 4, (1, 9): 4, (1, 10): 0, (1, 11): 0, (1, 12): 4, (1, 13): 4, (1, 14): 4}


This seems quite straightforward.  What have you tried?

You can generate two random values for each therapist; one for the value and one for which day to set to zero. Then, use an if-else statement when you create the dict that compares the d value, modulus 7, to see if it is the random day or the following day and, if so, use zero as the value otherwise use the random value:
import random

random_values_for_t = {
    t: (random.randint(1, 4), random.randint(1, 5))
    for t in range(1, 3)
}

max_td = {
    (t, d): (0 if d % 7 in (v[1], (v[1] + 1) % 7) else v[0])
    for t, v in random_values_for_t.items()
    for d in range(1, 15)
}

print(max_td)

Which may randomly output:
{(1, 1): 4, (1, 2): 4, (1, 3): 0, (1, 4): 0, (1, 5): 4, (1, 6): 4, (1, 7): 4, (1, 8): 4, (1, 9): 4, (1, 10): 0, (1, 11): 0, (1, 12): 4, (1, 13): 4, (1, 14): 4, (2, 1): 0, (2, 2): 0, (2, 3): 1, (2, 4): 1, (2, 5): 1, (2, 6): 1, (2, 7): 1, (2, 8): 0, (2, 9): 0, (2, 10): 1, (2, 11): 1, (2, 12): 1, (2, 13): 1, (2, 14): 1}


This does what you describe.  I assume you're trying to assign weekends here, so the series repeats every 7 days.  It would have been better if you had stated that in the question.
import random

T = list(range(1, 3))
D = list(range(1, 15))

random_values_for_t = {t: random.randint(1, 4) for t in T}

max_td = {(t, d): random_values_for_t[t] for t in T for d in D}

# Weekends start at a different day for each therapist.

lastone = -1
for t,d  in max_td:
    if t != lastone:
        choose = random.randrange(0,7)
        lastone = t
    if (d-choose) % 7 < 2:
        max_td[(t,d)] = 0

print(max_td)

Output:
{(1, 1): 1, (1, 2): 0, (1, 3): 0, (1, 4): 1, (1, 5): 1, (1, 6): 1, (1, 7): 1, (1, 8): 1, (1, 9): 0, (1, 10): 0, (1, 11): 1, (1, 12): 1, (1, 13): 1, (1, 14): 1, (2, 1): 0, (2, 2): 0, (2, 3): 1, (2, 4): 1, (2, 5): 1, (2, 6): 1, (2, 7): 1, (2, 8): 0, (2, 9): 0, (2, 10): 1, (2, 11): 1, (2, 12): 1, (2, 13): 1, (2, 14): 1}



The OP's requirement is "So for each t in T, a random day d<6 should be "drawn". The value there is then replaced by 0." It is not replacing day 3 and 4 but replacing a random day for each t.

Thank your sir. Is it also possible to use a different choose value for each t in T?

You should have been able to figure that out.
